# Use dataSnapshot variable

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
DatabaseReference nume_sofer = database.getReference("Rute").child("1").child("Sofer");

    nume_sofer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String sofer_nume = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    assert user != null;
    if(Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), sofer_nume)) {
```

Sorry, is it possible to use the variable *sofer_nume* from *onDataChange* in the *if* statement ? Thank you!
[image: Image code]

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see why your `sofer_nume` is `null` outside the callback and how can you solve it using a custom callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it outside the listener's scope then initialize it inside it so you could use it down in the if statement

Edit : check this

```
DatabaseReference nume_sofer = database.getReference("Rute").child("1").child("Sofer");    
String sofer_nume = null;

    nume_sofer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            sofer_nume = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    assert user != null;
    if(Objects.equals(user.getDisplayName(), sofer_nume)) {
```

Comment: I tried it, but the result is null

Comment: Check my edited code please

Comment: I edited the question by adding another picture, check it please

Comment: also I made it global, but sofer_nume is again null